# Verifying array values with C++11 range based loop? [Without vectors]

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, for-loop

I have an assignment that requires the program to read in 20 numbers from a user input into an array. 
The conditions require the value to be in between 10-100 and non repeated. I'm also only allowed to use one array with 20 elements. However, it's not supposed to prompt the user and simply doesn't store the value; finally the program has to print out the user's values that were unique. 
**Proper results For example:**

```
input = 9 10 15 15 15 0
output = 10 15
//this is a small example with a 6 element array instead of 20
```

**When I test my program I only get**

```
input: 9 10 15 15 15 0
output: 10 15 15 15
//this is a small example with a 6 element array instead of 20
```

I wrote the code using a range-based loop to check the values and set the value to 0 if it doesn't fulfill the conditions. So anything that isn't zero wouldn't be printed out. I've gone through all the questions on stack overflow and I couldn't find an answer to my **specific problems:**

- How to initialize all array element to zero using class constructors.
- Making it "static" so that when I run another function previous array values are global and maintained from the user input.
- *Something seems wrong about the loop I created but it looks perfect. I checked with my classmates and they agreed too.*

  ```
  //arrayinput.h
  #include <array>
  #include <string>

  class arrayelimination
  {
  public:
      const static size_t limit = 20; 
      arrayelimination();
      void inputArray();
      void displayArray();

  private:
      std::array < int , limit > store;
      int userinput;
  };



  //arrayinput.cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include <array>
  #include "arrayinput.h"
  using namespace std;

  arrayelimination::arrayelimination()
  {
  array < int , limit> store = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  }


  void arrayelimination::inputArray()
  {

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < store.size(); i++)
  {
      cout << "Enter number between 10-100 for array box [" 
          << i << "]: " ;
      cin >> userinput;
  //check if numbers is between 10-100
          if (userinput >= 10 && userinput <= 100)
      {
          //MOST LIKELY ERROR check if number has previously been used.
              for ( int &check : store) 
              {
                     if ( check != userinput)
                  {
                      store[i] = userinput;
                      break;
                  }
                  else
                      store[i] = 0;

              }
      }

      //output if number isn't between 10-100
  else 
      store[i] = 0;

  }
  }

  void arrayelimination::displayArray()
  {
          cout << "Your unique array numbers stored include...\n";
      //output all the unique numbers that the user inputted.  
  for ( size_t j = 0;  j < 20; j++)
  {
  //if the value is NOT 0, output.
      if (store[j] != 0)
      {
          cout << "array[ " << j << " ] = " << store[j] << "\n";
      }   
  }
  }
  ```

**When I test my program I only get**

```
input: 10 15 15 15 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0
output: 10 15 15 15
```

The concept of setting it to zero works but the repeated values aren't unique.

I have to use an object-oriented design as a requirement to this assignment. I'm near a dead-end I really don't know how this work. Please help me.

**PS: My bad I forgot to mention that I'm only allowed to use ONE array**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything wrong with just the standard algorithms?

```
int values[20];

// 1) read them in
for (int& v : values) {
    std::cin >> v;
}

// 2) sort/uniq
std::sort(std::begin(values), std::end(values));
auto last = std::unique(std::begin(values), std::end(values));

// 3) print them
std::for_each(values, last, [](const int v){
    std::cout << v << " ";
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I could only use one array to perform the task

Comment: **One array with only 20 elements. So sorry I should check over all the conditions

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't with the structure of the `range-based for loop` itself, but rather the problem is with your condition for checking if your input value is unique.

In this code block:

```
for ( int &check : store) 
{
    if ( check != userinput)
    {
        store[i] = userinput;
        break;
    }
    else
        store[i] = 0;
 }
```

You are setting the value of `userinput` encounters ANY element that it doesn't match. So the first element that doesn't match will cause you to set `userinput` even if `userinput` would match a value later in the array. What you need to be sure of is that `userinput` matches NO elements in the array.

For example:

```
for ( int &check : store) 
{
    if(check == userinput)
    {
        store[i] = 0;
        break;
    } // a match is found so set the value to 0 and stop
    else
    {
        store[i] = check;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already and what ends up happening is I guess these messed up values
`input: 10 15 15`
`output: -858993460  -858993460  -858993460`

Answer (score 0):

You're making this overly complicated.

1. Create empty vector. Don't even fill/resize it.
2. Add new elements with push_back. Add as many as you need.
3. Sort the array with std::sort.
4. Iterate through array, and print elements only if:
   4.1. It is the first element [i==0].
   4.2. OR it is not equal to previous element.

You can do the same thing with range-based loop as well.